# Weird behavior when encoding text into URL

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am really void and not able to understand the scenario.

My URL format:

```
http://api.xyz.com/pro/api/cities/Antigua%20and%20Barbuda
```

And it returns:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://api.xyz.com/pro/api/cities/Antigua%20and%20Barbuda.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

When I change the host with actual IP and port it works and return all cities:

```
http://10.10.10.10:9000/pro/api/cities/Antigua%20and%20Barbuda
```

1. First I thought there is some encoding issue. But, It is working
   with others text by encoding.
2. Second, I thought maybe multiple spaces or special characters cause
   this issue. But, it also works for other text like.

   ```
    http://api.xyz.com/pro/api/cities/Bolivia,%20Pluri%20State%20of
   ```

What I have observed until now is **"and" followed by space** is not working

```
1. http://api.xyz.com/pro/api/cities/Bosnia%20and%20Herzegovina
2. http://api.xyz.com/pro/api/cities/Heard%20Island%20and%20McDonald%20Mcdonald%20Islands
```

But, these all request with IP `10.10.10.10:9000` works perfectly.

I have tried it to change with query parameters too. But, the same error.

I have the solution to replace space to (-) and from BE replace (-) to space. But, I am curious to know why this behaving very weird?

I am sure that this might be because of **"and" followed by space** `%20and`.

### =====UPDATE======

`nginx` configuration:

```
server {
  listen 4200;
  gzip  on;
  gzip_types
  application/atom+xml
  application/javascript
  application/json
  application/rss+xml
  application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  application/x-font-ttf
  application/x-web-app-manifest+json
  application/xhtml+xml
  application/xml
  font/opentype
  image/svg+xml
  image/x-icon
  text/css
  text/plain
  text/x-component
  text/xml
  text/javascript;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
  location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        expires 1d;
  }
}
```

#### under `nginx`

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  6 08:44 conf.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1007 May 31  2016 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2837 May 31  2016 koi-utf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2223 May 31  2016 koi-win
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3957 May 31  2016 mime.types
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   22 May 31  2016 modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  643 May 31  2016 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  636 May 31  2016 scgi_params
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  664 May 31  2016 uwsgi_params
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3610 May 31  2016 win-utf
```

#### under conf.d

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  6 08:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep  6 08:44 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  634 Aug 31 11:24 default.conf
```

#### dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.11.1 as claims
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force
RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
# RUN mkdir ./ng-app/

# RUN npm i @angular/cli@1.3.1
# RUN npm i @angular/cli@1.3.1 -g
# RUN npm install npm@5.1.0

# RUN npm install

WORKDIR /ng-app
COPY . .
## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build

# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.10.1

COPY --from=claims /ng-app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: This is most probably an issue with your proxy (nginx, apache, or whatever you're using) if hitting the node service directly via the IP works just fine. I'd suggest checking that out, it might be that it's not very happy with your URL's for some reason or more likely you've got some incorrect configuration.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn Did not any special configuration. I am using `nginx`. What kind of configuration do I need to check?

Comment: I'm not an NGinx expert so it'll be worth tagging nginx in your question, but if this issue is not happening when hitting the node service directly, but it is when hitting via nginx then you've proven the node service is working just fine.

Comment: Yeah, Let me check with some `nginx` configuration then.

Comment: Can you post your nginx configuration?

Comment: @Paul, yes trying to get `nginx` configuration from the production server. As I am not facing this issue on `local`, `QA` or `dev` server. Will update and notify.

Comment: @Paul, updated with conf file.

Comment: That's not the right file. Do you have any sites configured in conf.d?

Comment: @Paul, under conf.d, I have only `default.conf` file. nonthing else

Comment: So, the strange thing is that your error indicates you’re using a self-signed SSL Certificate somewhere, but the NGINX configuration you’ve posted neither does SSL nor does it pass traffic to your node process.  This is why I think there’s another configuration you haven’t yet shared.

Comment: `error indicates you’re using a self-signed SSL Certificate` this is not exactly the error. Actually, this error is from postman and chrome. that usually shows when refused to the connection.

Comment: Ok, but it's also true that this nginx configuration makes no reference to the node app

Comment: Yes, so my problem is not from nxinx. Maybe something different.

Comment: There ar no any other configuration. I thought BE is also has sone configuration in `nginx` but there are only FE configuration are available. That means any requests to BE is not coming through `nginx`. There are nit any restrictions for any sites and don't want to do keep restrictions.

Comment: Ok, but if you have no NGINX connection to your node app then the ONLY away to get to it will be on port 9000 based on what you described as your current setup. Your URL pattern has nothing to do with that, the server simply has no way to send traffic to it without having the correct port. NGINX could proxy that for you over port 80 of course but you haven’t set that up.

Comment: `without having the correct port.` But there are 30 APIs running successfully only these what I have mentioned above are not working. One more thing is, those API not working is open(accessible without authToken). But please consider that without authToken some APIs are successfully working.

Comment: 9000 port is already forwarded from my IT team. Should I need to check with them to verify something? Is there might have some issue?